# bundle not found during eclipse feature install from command line

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I used

> eclipsec.exe
>
> ```
>    -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
>    -repository file:///d:/updatesite/target
>    -installIU myPlugin.feature.feature.group
>    -destination d:/eclipse/
>    -profile SDKProfile
> ```

but I get this error:
requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0' but it could not be found

NOTE: I built the feature using maven tycho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me when I added indigo update site to the current repository

```
   -repository file:///d:/updatesite/target,http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/
```

Comment: how can i have a local copy of indigo update site, so that it will not connect every time to internet and i have faced so many times the connection error if we put directly the indigo updatesite.

Comment: try adding -artifactRepository option and point to eclipse directory like:

`-artifactRepository file:///D:/eclipse`